Nginx location block allow/deny
I've tried to find the answer in this forum, reading Nginx location priority and others, but can't get this to work. It is regarding location blocks in Nginx.
I want to generally deny access to 'data' folders in Wordpress, but allow one instance. I have:
location ~ /(data|conf|bin|inc)/ {
    deny all;
}

... which I picked up as recommended somewhere for Wordpress.
I am trying to allow access to a certain 'data' folder for a plugin that needs it (Burst Statistics). I've tried variations of this, since the 'data' folder they need access to is a subfolder of 'wp-json/burst':
location ~ /(wp-json/burst) {
    allow all;
}

I've also tried:
location /wp-json/burst {
    allow all;
}

... and tried both of the above with trailing slashes, and put them both before and after the initial location line I mentioned at the top, as I know the order matters, but I'm not sure which way it should go.
The /wp-json/burst/ directory is a subdirectory of /var/www/wpdir/ in the Wordpress setup, so I think I should use the former example, with location ~ /(wp-json/burst), correct?
What can I do to get this to work, so that I can deny access to 'data' subfolders within Wordpress, but allow it for this one location?
Thanks for any help.
